# How to declare a class for a calculator?

Tags: class, haskell, declaration

I am trying to build my own calculator in Haskell with class declaration.

Firstly, I was trying to implement the addition, but here I got the error:

> Couldn't match expected type 'Exp -> Double' with actual type 'Exp'

```hs
data Exp = Number Double | Add Exp Exp 


class Calc a where
 calculate :: a -> a -> Double

instance Calc Exp where
 calculate (Add a b) = a + b
```

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need, nor would I recommend, a class here. Just define an ordinary function that handles each of the data constructors separately. (Use a class only if you expect to have multiple *types* that can be used with `calculate`.)

In either case, `calculate` takes a *single* argument, as your type represents an entire expression, operands and operator together.

```
calculate :: Exp -> Double
calculate (Number n) = ...
calculate (Add a b) = ...
```

Keep in mind that `a` and `b` are values of type `Exp`, not numbers (i.e., types with a `Num` instance) that you can add directly. (This suggests you need to *recursively* calculate the value of `a` and `b` before you can actually perform addition.)

Some test cases for you to consider:

```
n1 = Number 2.0
n2 = Add (Number 3.0) (4.0))
n3 = Add n1 n2

map calculate [n1, n2, n3] == [2.0, 7.0, 9.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by chepner, your `calculate` function need only take a single argument. You also need to account for the possibility that each `Exp` value maybe be a `Number` and handle that in the function.

Since `a` and `b` are `Exp` values and not `Num` instances, you will need to apple `calculate` to them.

```
data Exp = Number Double | Add Exp Exp 

class Calc a where
 calculate :: a -> Double

instance Calc Exp where
 calculate (Number n) = n
 calculate (Add a b) = a' + b'
  where a' = ...
  where b' = ...
```

But you *might* consider making Exp an instance of `Num`. The below is incomplete as it doesn't account for actual expressions except for `+`, but it might hint at what's possible.

```
instance Num Exp where
 (+) (Number n1) (Number n2) = Number (n1 + n2)
 (+) (Add a b) c@(Number _) = a + b + c
 (+) a@(Number _) (Add b c) = a + b + c
 (+) (Add a b) (Add c d) = a + b + c + d
 (*) (Number n1) (Number n2) = Number (n1 * n2)
 abs (Number n) = Number (abs n)
 negate (Number n) = Number (negate n)
 signum (Number n) = Number (signum n)
 fromInteger n = Number (fromIntegral n)
```

```
ghci> case Add (Number 5) (Number 6) + Number 7 of { Number n -> n }
18.0
```

Comment: I like this one. Thank you.